# mysql - Calculating profit of sales between dates

Tags: mysql, sql, business-intelligence

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| PartNo | Date                | Inv   | Retail | Wholesale |
+--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
| 1      | 2018-05-12 00:00:00 | 15    | $100   | $90       |
| 2      | 2018-05-12 00:00:00 | 20    | $200   | $150      |
| 3      | 2018-05-12 00:00:00 | 25    | $300   | $200      |
| 1      | 2018-05-13 00:00:00 | 10    | $95    | $90       |
| 2      | 2018-05-14 00:00:00 | 15    | $200   | $150      |
| 3      | 2018-05-14 00:00:00 | 20    | $300   | $200      |
+--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-----------+
```

And I want it to look like this with a Mysql query:

```
+--------+------+--------+
| PartNo | Sold | Profit |
+--------+------+--------+
| 1      | 5    | $25    |
| 2      | 5    | $250   |
| 3      | 5    | $500   |
+--------+------+--------+
```

I need to group by PartNo while calculating the difference between totals and profits over a date range.

The unit profit has to be calculated by subtracting the wholesale from retail on the last day (or record) of the date range.

I feel like this should be easy but the differences over the date ranges are confusing me and handling records within the date range that don't start or end exactly on the date range input are losing me.

Any help would be super appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why is the result 5 Sold for PartNo 123456 ?

Comment: When having sample data, it's much easier to read values like 1, 2, and 3, instead of 123456, 456789 and 147258.

Comment: I think I have to have something along these lines at the end of my statement.

WHERE 
    Date >= '2018-05-10' 
  AND 
    Date < '2018-05-14' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY 
    PartNo; 

Getting the profit sums and total sums is throwing me.

Comment: How do you get 25 profit for 123456? as far as I can see (100 - 90) + (95 - 90) = 15

Comment: Sorry jarlh, I thought I was dumbing it down but I can see your point. The real partnos are 16 chars.

Comment: Read up on the [GROUP BY Clause](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) to make a group then use some calculations in your query to generate the Profit.

Comment: PN 123456 has a change in retail price at the last date, therefore the profit goes to $25 after selling 5 and using the last days margin. Perhaps I should be using the previous day margin, I suppose it all boils down to running this in the morning or COB.

Comment: BTW, totals are not units sold, they are units on the shelf or inventory.

Comment: Thanks MBijen, the Group by would be straightforward is the totals were units sold but because I have to calculate units sold based on the difference from one day to the next, incorporating the arithmetic is throwing me.

Comment: Just made the PN's simpler

Comment: I understood the question incorrectly. I thought each row was 1 order.

Comment: Tip: Don't store '$'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up the situation at the start and at the end of the period  If no start situation is found, assume no stock.  If no end situation is found, that means no sales during the period.

For example for the period starting `2018-05-13` and ending `2018-05-14`:

```
select  parts.PartNo
,       coalesce(FirstSale.Total, 0) - coalesce(LastSale.Total, FirstSale.Total, 0) as Sold
,       (coalesce(FirstSale.Total, 0) - coalesce(LastSale.Total, FirstSale.Total, 0)) *
           coalesce(LastSale.Retail - LastSale.Wholesale, 0) as Profit
from    (
        select  PartNo
        ,       max(case when Date < '2018-05-13' then Date end) as FirstEntry
        ,       max(case when Date <= '2018-05-14' then Date end) as LastEntry
        from    Sales
        group by
                PartNo
        ) parts
left join    
        Sales FirstSale
on      FirstSale.PartNo = parts.PartNo
        and FirstSale.Date = parts.FirstEntry
left join    
        Sales LastSale
on      LastSale.PartNo = parts.PartNo
        and LastSale.Date = parts.LastEntry
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/836bb/5/0)

Comment: Andomar, great straight forward solution. Worked fine on my example and small table. I think something about the sub-select to 'parts' and the two left joins is creating a big performance hit on a input table with 60k rows. Any performance recommendations would be appreciated. Thanks a ton for this!

Comment: It's okay if a reporting query runs for a while? If speed is important, you could try an index on `PartNo, Date, Total, Retail, Wholesale`.  A client side solution could also speed things up (for example, read the relevant rows into a Python script)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.partno as partno,MAX(c.inv)-MIN(c.inv) as sold,SUM(CASE WHEN c.date = c.last_date THEN profit else 0 END)*(MAX(c.inv)-MIN(c.inv)) as profit
FROM (SELECT partno,date,inv,retail-wholesale as profit,MAX(date) OVER (partition by partno) AS last_date FROM test1)c
GROUP BY c.partno
ORDER BY c.partno;
```

Using the **window function**, first append a new column to track the max date for each partno. So the inner query inside **FROM** will produce rows like these with one column added to the the original dataset,

```
| 1      | 2018-05-12 00:00:00 | 15    | $100   | $90       | **2018-05-13 00:00:00** |
```

The highlighted field is the one added to the dataset which is the last date in the date range for that part number!

Now from this result, we can pull out profit by checking for the row in which date column is equal to the new column we appended, which is essentially calculating the profit for the last date by subtracting wholesale from retail and multiplying with items sold.

PS : The logic for items sold is grouping by partno and subtracting MIN(Inv) from MAX(Inv)

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d0536/1)

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution but it uses the OVER(partition) which is not available in my version of mysql. Thank you very much.